# MySQL JOIN returns NULL fields

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run script below, but always getting NULL values for name field.

```
SELECT u.name AS _user_name, s.name AS _school_name
FROM fwg_files AS f
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = f.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_profiles AS up ON up.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN school AS s ON s.id = up.profile_value
```

The problem seems to me in JOIN ON school table, I tried to SELECT s.id and it returns NULL values also.

Table fwg_files

```
id  | user_id
240 | 414
241 | 436
```

Table users

```
id  | name
414 | Name 1
436 | Name 2
```

Table user_profiles

```
user_id | profile_value
414     | "6"
436     | "14"
```

Table school

```
id | name

 6 | School 1
14 | School 2
```

Thank you

Comment: Please show a record each from the users and userprofiles tables

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your data and the Schema, but if up.profile_value  is like "123", you can try this:

```
SELECT u.name AS _user_name, s.name AS _school_name
FROM fwg_files AS f
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.id = f.user_id
LEFT JOIN user_profiles AS up ON up.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN school AS s ON CONCAT('"', s.id, '"') = up.profile_value
```